# The layer is masked by a `CAShapeLayer` with a path that's a rect, a rounded-rect, or an ellipse

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer

I'm trying to create a view that can have different values for each of the corners. Everything works as expected but in the **Vide Debug** mode I get an optimization opportunities warning, which says:

**The layer is masked by a `CAShapeLayer` with a path that's a rect, a rounded-rect, or an ellipse. Instead, use an appropriately transformed container layer with `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds` set.**

I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same effect, here's my current code:

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    convenience init(
        shouldRoundRect rect: CGRect,
        topLeftRadius: CGFloat,
        topRightRadius: CGFloat,
        bottomLeftRadius: CGFloat,
        bottomRightRadius: CGFloat
    ){
        self.init()

        let path = CGMutablePath()

        let topLeft = rect.origin
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY)

        if topLeftRadius != 0 {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + topLeftRadius, y: topLeft.y))
        } else {
            path.move(to: topLeft)
        }

        if topRightRadius != 0 {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topRight.x - topRightRadius, y: topRight.y))
            path.addArc(tangent1End: topRight, tangent2End: CGPoint(x: topRight.x, y: topRight.y + topRightRadius), radius: topRightRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: topRight)
        }

        if bottomRightRadius != 0 {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomRight.x, y: bottomRight.y - bottomRightRadius))
            path.addArc(tangent1End: bottomRight, tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bottomRight.x - bottomRightRadius, y: bottomRight.y), radius: bottomRightRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: bottomRight)
        }

        if bottomLeftRadius != 0 {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeft.x + bottomLeftRadius, y: bottomLeft.y))
            path.addArc(tangent1End: bottomLeft, tangent2End: CGPoint(x: bottomLeft.x, y: bottomLeft.y - bottomLeftRadius), radius: bottomLeftRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
        }

        if topLeftRadius != 0 {
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x, y: topLeft.y + topLeftRadius))
            path.addArc(tangent1End: topLeft, tangent2End: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + topLeftRadius, y: topLeft.y), radius: topLeftRadius)
        } else {
            path.addLine(to: topLeft)
        }

        path.closeSubpath()
        cgPath = path
    }
}

class CornerRadiusView: UIView  {
    private var topLeftRadius: CGFloat = 0
    private var topRightRadius: CGFloat = 0
    private var bottomLeftRadius: CGFloat = 0
    private var bottomRightRadius: CGFloat = 0
    
    func setCornerRadius(radius: CornerRadius) {
        topLeftRadius = radius.topLeft
        topRightRadius = radius.topRight
        bottomLeftRadius = radius.bottomLeft
        bottomRightRadius = radius.bottomRight
        
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        applyRadiusMask()
    }
    
    private func applyRadiusMask() {
        let path = UIBezierPath(
            shouldRoundRect: bounds,
            topLeftRadius: topLeftRadius,
            topRightRadius: topRightRadius,
            bottomLeftRadius: bottomLeftRadius,
            bottomRightRadius: bottomRightRadius
        )
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = shape
    }
}

struct CornerRadius {
    let topLeft: CGFloat
    let topRight: CGFloat
    let bottomLeft: CGFloat
    let bottomRight: CGFloat
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this: https://github.com/shamzahasan88/HHCustomCorner/blob/master/Classes/HHCustomCornerView.swift

Comment: It's just a suggestion. If you're not having any performance issues, ignore it.

Comment: Simple is that you are not using view.layer.cornerRadius that's why showing these warnings. and of course you can not use it because you need different value on different corner, you can see it just tapping on Debug View Hierarchy